# How to html5 video duration speed control bypass

Tags: javascript, video, controls, html5-video, duration

I am not a web developer. The institution I work for has online training. in html5 video form. Video acceleration doesn't work. There is a time control. If speeding is detected, the video restarts. Is there any way I can bypass this? The total duration of the trainings is 650 min. It is really hard. I am posting the source code of the video page.

```
<div style="position:relative">
<input type="hidden" id="pinfo" data-calisankodu="46564064386" data-calisanadsoyad="FATİH KURT" data-egitimkodu="1ae2b8e4-971f-4025-a8e2-97cbc60989bd"
       data-egitimadi="2022 Temel İş Sağlığı ve G&#252;venliği Eğitimi" data-dokumankodu="35c46809-cc58-4806-a5e8-e921d65b8557" data-dosyaadi="01 Genel Konular_202104042129579656.mp4" data-dokumantanimi="01 genel konular"
       data-dokumanaciklama="Genel Konular" data-calisanegitimkodu="dad47501-bdd3-4275-a01e-631e77ecc242" data-calisanegitimicerikkodu="d3439fcb-ad6b-41dd-bd87-592ba6f47325"
       data-ks="765" data-kontrolkaldigisure="0" data-ts="2768" data-td="27" data-uzanti="mp4" data-vapo="1"
       data-vks="0" data-isyerikodu="AEFC7F5C-7FA2-4A9E-83A3-6FED40C4A829" />

<div id="kontrolSorular" class="hidden"></div>
<div id="video-filigram" style="margin-left: 0px;" class="grid-stack hidden"></div>
<video id="dersvideo" playsinline controls preload="auto">
    <source src="/UploadedFiles/01 Genel Konular_202104042129579656.mp4" type="video/mp4" size="1080">
    Tarayıcınız video oynatmayı desteklemiyor.
```

And

```
//Genel değişkenler
    var player;
    var icerik = {};
    var aktifsoru = 0;
    var kconfirms = [];
    var kontrolsorular = [];
    var currenttime = 0;
    var kontrolsure = 0;
    var completedbefore = false;
    var videoarkaplandaoynat = false;
    var seektry = false;
    var autosavesecond = 120;
    var savetries = [];
    var savetryconfirmed = false;
    var isios = false;
    var loadeddata = false;
    var ilerisarma = 0;
    var zorunluegitim = 1;
    var kontrolegitimicerik = "";
    var etkilesimliegitimicerik = "";
    var EtkilesimliEgitimIzlenecekDokumanKodu = "";
    var cevaplanankontrolegitimicerik = [];
    var cevaplananetkilesimliegitimicerik = [];
    var kontrolegitimiceriksure = -1;
    var etkilesimliegitimiceriksure = -1;
    var gecensure = 0;
    var EgitimTuru = "1";
    var VideoIleriSarma = "0";

    if (EgitimTuru == "0" || VideoIleriSarma == "1") {
        console.log("Video ileri sarma aktif");
        ilerisarma = 5;
        zorunluegitim = 0;
    }

    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/g)) {
        console.log("iOS device detected");
        console.log("Everything is OK.");
        isios = true;
    }

    //Doc Ready
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Load lesson content
        icerik = {
            CalisanKodu: $("#pinfo").attr("data-calisankodu"),
            CalisanAdSoyad: $("#pinfo").attr("data-calisanadsoyad"),
            EgitimKodu: $("#pinfo").attr("data-egitimkodu"),
            EgitimAdi: $("#pinfo").attr("data-egitimadi"),
            DokumanKodu: $("#pinfo").attr("data-dokumankodu"),
            DosyaAdi: $("#pinfo").attr("data-dosyaadi"),
            DokumanTanimi: $("#pinfo").attr("data-dokumantanimi"),
            DokumanAciklama: $("#pinfo").attr("data-dokumanaciklama"),
            CalisanEgitimKodu: $("#pinfo").attr("data-calisanegitimkodu"),
            CalisanEgitimIcerikKodu: $("#pinfo").attr("data-calisanegitimicerikkodu"),
            ToplamSure: parseInt($("#pinfo").attr("data-ts")),
            KaldigiSure: parseInt($("#pinfo").attr("data-ks")),
            KontrolKaldigiSure: parseInt($("#pinfo").attr("data-kontrolkaldigisure")),
            TamamlanmaDurum: parseInt($("#pinfo").attr("data-td")),
            Tamamlandi: false,
            KontrolSure: -1,
            EgitimKontrolIcerikKodu: kontrolegitimicerik,
            EtkilesimliEgitimIcerikKodu: etkilesimliegitimicerik,
            EgitimTuru: EgitimTuru,
            GecenSure: 0
        };

        //Get lesson state
        if (icerik.TamamlanmaDurum >= 100) {
            completedbefore = true;
            icerik.Tamamlandi = true;
        }
        //Player Install
        player = new Plyr('#dersvideo', {
            controls: ['play-large', 'play', 'progress', 'current-time', 'mute', 'volume', 'settings', 'fullscreen'],
            settings: ['captions','quality' /*,'speed' */ ],
            preload: "auto",
            i18n: {
                restart: 'Sıfırla',
                rewind: 'Kalan {seektime}',
                play: 'Başlat',
                pause: 'Durdur',
                fastForward: 'İleri {seektime}',
                seek: 'Aralık',
                seekLabel: '{currentTime} of {duration}',
                played: 'Oynatılan',
                buffered: 'Önbellek',
                currentTime: 'Şimdi',
                duration: 'Süre',
                volume: 'Ses',
                mute: 'Sustur',
                unmute: 'Sesi Aç',
                enableCaptions: 'Altyazı Aç',
                disableCaptions: 'Altyazı Kapat',
                download: 'İndir',
                enterFullscreen: 'Tam Ekran',
                exitFullscreen: 'Kapat',
                frameTitle: 'Oynatılıyor: {title}',
                captions: 'Altyazılar',
                settings: 'Ayarlar',
                menuBack: 'Geri',
                speed: 'Hız',
                normal: 'Normal',
                quality: 'Kalite',
                loop: 'Tekrar',
                start: 'Başlangıç',
                end: 'Son',
                all: 'Tümü',
                reset: 'Sıfırla',
                disabled: 'Gizle',
                enabled: 'Göster',
                advertisement: 'Duyuru',
                qualityBadge: {
                    1080: 'Yuksek',
                    360: 'Dusuk',
                },
                capture: 'Ekran Görüntüsü'
            },
            keyboard:{ focused: false, global: false },
            seekTime: ilerisarma,
            fullscreen: { fallback: false },
            listeners: {
                seek: function (e) {
                    seektry = true;
                    var newTime = _getTargetTime(player, e);
                    if (newTime > icerik.KaldigiSure && completedbefore == false && zorunluegitim == "1") {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        console.log('prevented');
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        var vh = $(window).innerHeight();
        let vw = $(window).innerWidth();
        $("#dersvideo").css("height", vh + "px");

        $(window).resize(function () {
            let vh = $(window).innerHeight();
            let vw = $(window).innerWidth();
            $("#dersvideo").css("height", vh + "px");
        });

        $(window).bind("resize", function () {
            let vh = $(window).innerHeight();
            let vw = $(window).innerWidth();
            $("#dersvideo").css("height", vh + "px");
        });

       
        //Get backgroundplay config
        if ($("#pinfo").attr("data-vapo") == "1") {
            videoarkaplandaoynat = true;
        }

        //Get client control config
        if (Number($("#pinfo").attr("data-vks")) > 0) {
            kontrolsure = Number($("#pinfo").attr("data-vks"))*60;
        } else {
            kontrolsure = Number(icerik.KontrolSure);
        }

        player.on('play', event => {
            start();
        });

        player.on('pause', event => {
            stop();
        });

        
        if (isios) {
            //On play
            player.once('play', event => {
                console.log("duration: " + parseInt(player.duration) + " - After First Play");
                icerik.ToplamSure = parseInt(player.duration);
                player.currentTime = (icerik.KontrolKaldigiSure == 0) ? icerik.KaldigiSure : icerik.KontrolKaldigiSure;
            });
        } else {
            //ShowWelcome();
            if (icerik.Tamamlandi == false) {
                console.log("start lesson");
                player.play();

            } else {
                player.currentTime = (icerik.KontrolKaldigiSure == 0) ? 0 : icerik.KontrolKaldigiSure;
                player.play();
            }
            player.play();
            //On player get video data
            player.once('loadeddata', event => {
                loadeddata = true;
                ShowButtons();
            });

            setTimeout(function () {

        }

        //player.on('enterfullscreen', event => { console.log(event); });
        //player.on('exitfullscreen', event => { console.log(event); });

        //Player on time update
        player.on('timeupdate', event => {

            currenttime = parseInt(player.currentTime);

            if (currenttime > icerik.KaldigiSure || icerik.Tamamlandi == true) {
                icerik.KaldigiSure = currenttime;
            }

            //Kontrol süresi özelliği eklendiğinde açılacak.
            if (kontrolsure > 0 && player.playing && currenttime > 0 && currenttime % kontrolsure == 0) {
                var cfrm = kconfirms.filter(x => x == currenttime);
                if (cfrm.length == 0) {
                    kconfirms.push(currenttime);
                    player.pause();

                }
            }

            /

            // Eğitim Kontrol İçeriği Tetikletme
            if (currenttime == kontrolegitimiceriksure && player.playing == true && cevaplanankontrolegitimicerik.indexOf(kontrolegitimicerik) == -1){
                $("#video-filigram").removeClass("hidden");
                player.pause();
                SaveState(false);
                $(".jconfirm").remove();
            }

            // Etkileşimli Eğitim İçeriği Tetikletme
            if (currenttime == etkilesimliegitimiceriksure && player.playing == true && cevaplananetkilesimliegitimicerik.indexOf(etkilesimliegitimicerik) == -1) {
                player.pause();
                SaveState(false);
                $(".jconfirm").remove();
                window.location.href = "/Calisan/EtkilesimliIcerikViewer/" + etkilesimliegitimicerik + window.location.search + "&etkilesimliegitimicerik=" + etkilesimliegitimicerik + "&kaldigisure=" + player.currentTime + "&isyerikodu=" + $("#pinfo").attr("data-isyerikodu");

            }

        });

        player.on('seeking', event => {
            if (zorunluegitim=="0" || icerik.KaldigiSure >= player.currentTime || // video başı mı ?
                ((parseInt(kontrolegitimiceriksure) != parseInt(player.currentTime) && kontrolegitimiceriksure != -1)) ||
                ((parseInt(etkilesimliegitimiceriksure) != parseInt(player.currentTime) && etkilesimliegitimiceriksure != -1)) //|| kontrol içeriği var mı ve süre eşit mi ?
                //parseInt(player.currentTime) == parseInt(player.duration) // video sonuna gelindi mi ?
                //seektry == true
            ) {
            }
            else {
                SaveState(true);
            }
        });

        //Pause event
        player.on('pause', event => {
            console.log("paused");

            if (parseInt(player.currentTime) == parseInt(player.duration)) {
                if (player.currentTime < player.duration && (kontrolegitimiceriksure == -1 || etkilesimliegitimiceriksure == -1) ) {
                   LessonEnd();
                }
                //Respect end event
            } else if (seektry == true) {
                console.log("seektry");
                seektry = false;
            } else if (!player.fullscreen.active && aktifsoru == 0 && savetryconfirmed == false) {
                if (parseInt(kontrolegitimiceriksure) != parseInt(player.currentTime) || parseInt(etkilesimliegitimiceriksure) != parseInt(player.currentTime))
                {
                    $.confirm({
                        theme: 'supervan',
                        closeIcon: false,
                        title: 'Video Duraklatıldı',
                        content: completedbefore == false ? 'Videoya kaldığınız yerden devam edebilir ya da eğitimi sonlandırabilirsiniz.<br/><br/> <small><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> UYARI <br/> Eğitimi sonlandırırsanız bu içerik tamamlanmamış olarak kaydedilecektir.</small>' : 'Videoya kaldığınız yerden devam edebilir ya da eğitimi sonlandırabilirsiniz.',
                        typeAnimated: true,
                        onContentReady: function () {
                            $(document).on("mousedown touchstart", function () {
                                $(document).find(".jconfirm-bg").css("background-color", "rgba(54,70,93,0.25)");
                            });
                            $(document).on("mouseup touchstart", function () {
                                $(document).find(".jconfirm-bg").css("background-color", "rgba(54,70,93,0.95)");
                            });
                        },
                        buttons: {
                            basla: {
                                text: '<i class="fa fa-play" style="margin-right:10px;"></i> Devam Et',
                                btnClass: 'btn-green',
                                action: function () {
                                    player.play();
                                    //SaveState(false);
                                }
                            },
                            kapat: {
                                text: '<i class="fa fa-times" style="margin-right:10px;"></i> Bitir',
                                btnClass: 'btn-red',
                                action: function () {
                                    if (completedbefore == true) {
                                        window.location.href = $("#routebase").val() + "Calisan/EgitimDetay/" + icerik.EgitimKodu + '?isyerikodu='+$("#pinfo").attr("data-isyerikodu");
                                    } else {
                                        SaveState(true);
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            gizle: {
                                text: '<i class="fa fa-eye-slash" style="margin-right:10px;"></i> Gizle',
                                btnClass: 'btn-red',
                                action: function () {
                                    $(".jconfirm").remove();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        //End event
        player.on('ended', event => {
            if (((currenttime == kontrolegitimiceriksure || currenttime == icerik.KontrolKaldigiSure) && cevaplanankontrolegitimicerik.length !== 0 && cevaplanankontrolegitimicerik.indexOf(kontrolegitimicerik)) == -1 || ((currenttime == etkilesimliegitimiceriksure || currenttime == icerik.KontrolKaldigiSure) && cevaplananetkilesimliegitimicerik.length !== 0 && cevaplananetkilesimliegitimicerik.indexOf(etkilesimliegitimicerik) == -1)) {
                $("#video-filigram").removeClass("hidden");
                player.pause();

                SaveState(false);
                $(".jconfirm").remove();

            } else if (currenttime != icerik.KontrolKaldigiSure) {
                LessonEnd(/*otomatikdevamet:*/true);
            }
        });

        $(window).on('blur', windowBlurred);

        $(window).on('focus', windowFocused);

        $(document).on("contextmenu", function () {
            return false;
        });

        $(document).on("click", "#ksCevapla", function () {
            var soru = kontrolsorular.find(x => x.ID == "" + aktifsoru);
            var vc = $('input[name="ks"]:checked').val();
            var msg = "";
            if (typeof vc == "undefined") {
                alert("Lütfen soruyu cevaplayınız.");
            } else if (vc == soru.DOGRUCEVAP) {
                msg = "Tebrikler. Doğru Cevap.";
                $("#ksmsg").html(msg).removeClass("text-red").addClass("text-green");
                soru.SORULDU = true;
                soru.VERILENCEVAP = vc;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    HideKs();
                    player.play();
                }, 2000);
            } else {
                msg = "Üzgünüz. Yanlış cevap.";
                msg += soru.AKSIYONZAMAN != "" ? " İlgili bölüme yönlendiriliyor..." : "";
                $("#ksmsg").html(msg).removeClass("text-green").addClass("text-red");
                soru.SORULDU = true;
                soru.VERILENCEVAP = vc;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    HideKs();
                    if (soru.AKSIYONZAMAN != "") {
                        player.currentTime = Number(soru.AKSIYONZAMAN);
                        player.play();
                    }
                }, 3000);
            }
        });

    });

    function ShowWelcome() {
        //Show welcome message
            $.confirm({
                theme: 'supervan',
                closeIcon: false,
                title: 'Sn. ' + icerik.CalisanAdSoyad,
                content: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Ders içeriğiniz hazırlanıyor...',
                typeAnimated: true,
                onContentReady: function () {
                    if (isios) {
                        ShowButtons();
                    }
                    $(document).on("mousedown touchstart", function () {
                        $(document).find(".jconfirm-bg").css("background-color", "rgba(54,70,93,0.25)");
                    });
                    $(document).on("mouseup touchstart", function () {
                        $(document).find(".jconfirm-bg").css("background-color", "rgba(54,70,93,0.95)");
                    });
                },
                buttons: {
                    basla: {
                        text: '<i class="fa fa-play" style="margin-right:10px;"></i> Başla',
                        btnClass: 'btn-green basla actionbtn hidden',
                        action: function () {
                            if (icerik.Tamamlandi == false) {
                                console.log("start lesson");
                                player.play();
                            } else {
                                player.currentTime = (icerik.KontrolKaldigiSure == 0) ? 0 : icerik.KontrolKaldigiSure;
                                player.play();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    kapat: {
                        text: '<i class="fa fa-times" style="margin-right:10px;"></i> Vazgeç',
                        btnClass: 'btn-red vazgec actionbtn hidden',
                        action: function () {
                            window.location.href = $("#routebase").val() + "Calisan/EgitimDetay/" + icerik.EgitimKodu + '?isyerikodu=' + $("#pinfo").attr("data-isyerikodu");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    function ShowButtons() {
        player.currentTime = (icerik.KontrolKaldigiSure == 0) ? icerik.KaldigiSure : icerik.KontrolKaldigiSure;
        icerik.ToplamSure = parseInt(player.duration);

        var dersInfo = '<b>' + icerik.EgitimAdi + '</b> eğitiminin<br/> <b> ' + icerik.DokumanTanimi + '</b> başlıklı içeriği hazırlandı. <br/><br/> <small><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> UYARI <br/> Video tamamlanmadan çıkmanız halinde eğitiminiz tamamlanmamış olarak kaydedilecektir.</small>';
        if (completedbefore) {
            dersInfo = '<div><b>' + icerik.EgitimAdi + '</b> eğitiminin<br/> <b> ' + icerik.DokumanTanimi + '</b> başlıklı içeriğini daha önce tamamladınız.<br/><br/> Yeniden izlemek için lütfen Başla butonuna basınız.</div>';
        }

        $(document).find(".jconfirm-content").html(dersInfo);
        $(document).find(".actionbtn").removeClass("hidden");
    }

    function LessonEnd(otomatikdevamet = false) {
        icerik.Tamamlandi = true;
        icerik.KaldigiSure = parseInt(player.duration);

        if (otomatikdevamet == true) {

            SaveState(false);
            var url = '/Calisan/VideoViewer/?dk=b0af9b9e-dfdb-4651-8305-bf5891c29633&ek=1ae2b8e4-971f-4025-a8e2-97cbc60989bd&cei=87e3b3d1-1b0e-4fcd-a5ba-2b803c93ac27&cek=dad47501-bdd3-4275-a01e-631e77ecc242&isyerikodu=AEFC7F5C-7FA2-4A9E-83A3-6FED40C4A829';
            if (url != "" && url != null && url != undefined) {
                var decodedurl = url.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
                window.location.href = decodedurl;
            } else {
                LessonEnd();
            }
        } else {
            $.confirm({
                theme: 'supervan',
                closeIcon: false,
                title: 'İçerik Tamamlandı',
                content: completedbefore == false ? 'Tebrikler. Eğitim içeriğini başarıyla tamamladınız.' : 'Video sona erdi.',
                typeAnimated: true,
                onOpenBefore: function () {

                    var SonrakiIcerikDurumu = "1";
                    if (SonrakiIcerikDurumu != "1") {
                        $(".sonrakiislemler").remove();
                    }
                },
                buttons: {
                    basla: {
                        text: '<i class="fa fa-play" style="margin-right:10px;"></i> Eğitim Sayfasına Dön',
                        btnClass: 'btn-green',
                        action: function () {
                            if (completedbefore == true) {
                                window.location.href = $("#routebase").val() + "Calisan/EgitimDetay/" + icerik.EgitimKodu + '?isyerikodu=' + $("#pinfo").attr("data-isyerikodu");
                            } else {
                                SaveState(true);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    kapat: {
                        text: '<i class="fa fa-undo" style="margin-right:10px;"></i> Yeniden İzle',
                        btnClass: 'btn-green',
                        action: function () {
                            player.currentTime = 0;
                            player.play();
                        }
                    },
                    sonraki: {
                        text: '<i id="sonrakiislemicon" class="fa fa-step-forward" style="margin-right:10px;"></i> <span id="sonrakiislem"> Sonraki İçerik </span>',
                        btnClass: 'btn-green sonrakiislemler',
                        action: function () {

                            var url = '/Calisan/VideoViewer/?dk=b0af9b9e-dfdb-4651-8305-bf5891c29633&amp;ek=1ae2b8e4-971f-4025-a8e2-97cbc60989bd&amp;cei=87e3b3d1-1b0e-4fcd-a5ba-2b803c93ac27&amp;cek=dad47501-bdd3-4275-a01e-631e77ecc242&amp;isyerikodu=AEFC7F5C-7FA2-4A9E-83A3-6FED40C4A829';
                            var decodedurl = url.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
                            window.location.href = decodedurl;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    var kaldigimsure = 0;
    function windowBlurred() {
        kaldigimsure = player.currentTime.toFixed(0);
        if (videoarkaplandaoynat == false) {
            player.pause();

            //if (kaldigimsure > player.currentTime.toFixed(0)) {
            //    setTimeout(function () {
            //        window.location.href = $("#routebase").val() + "Calisan/EgitimDetay/" + icerik.EgitimKodu + '?isyerikodu=' + $("#pinfo").attr("data-isyerikodu");
            //    }, 750);
            //}
        }
    }

    function windowFocused() {
        if (videoarkaplandaoynat == false) {
            //if (kaldigimsure > player.currentTime.toFixed(0)) {
            //    setTimeout(function () {
            //        window.location.href = $("#routebase").val() + "Calisan/EgitimDetay/" + icerik.EgitimKodu + '?isyerikodu=' + $("#pinfo").attr("data-isyerikodu");
            //    }, 750);
            //}
        }
    }

    function SaveState(exit) {

        if (completedbefore == false) {

            var maxduration = parseInt(player.duration);
            var percentage = 100 * icerik.KaldigiSure / maxduration;
            icerik.TamamlanmaDurum = percentage >= 100 ? 100 : parseInt(percentage);
            var currentorder = savetries.length;

            var savetry = {
                order: currentorder,
                time: moment().format("DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss"),
                duration: currenttime,
                state: false,
                error: ""
            };
            savetries.push(savetry);
            icerik.IsyeriKodu = $("#pinfo").attr("data-isyerikodu");
            icerik.GecenSure = gecensure;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Calisan/VideoDurumKaydet',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: icerik,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.state) {
                        savetries[currentorder].state = true;
                        if (completedbefore == false && icerik.Tamamlandi == true) {
                            completedbefore = true;
                        }
                        if (exit) {
                            if (data.tumiceriktamam == true && data.sonsinavotomatikbaslat == true) {
                                alertify.success("Eğitim sınavına yönlendiriliyorsunuz. Lütfen bekleyin.");
                                setTimeout(function () {
                                    window.location.href = $("#routebase").val() + data.sonsinavhref;
                                }, 750);
                            } else {
                                alertify.success("Eğitim durumu kaydedildi. Lütfen bekleyin.");
                                setTimeout(function () {
                                    window.location.href = $("#routebase").val() + "Calisan/EgitimDetay/" + icerik.EgitimKodu + '?isyerikodu=' + $("#pinfo").attr("data-isyerikodu");
                                }, 750);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (data.tumiceriktamam == true && data.sonsinavotomatikbaslat == true) {
                                alertify.success("Eğitim sınavına yönlendiriliyorsunuz. Lütfen bekleyin.");
                                setTimeout(function () {
                                    window.location.href = $("#routebase").val() + data.sonsinavhref;
                                }, 750);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        savetries[currentorder].state = false;
                        savetries[currentorder].error = data.message;

                        if (data.state == false) {
                            alertify.error(data.message);
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                window.location.href = $("#routebase").val() + "Calisan/EgitimDetay/" + icerik.EgitimKodu + '?isyerikodu=' + $("#pinfo").attr("data-isyerikodu");
                            }, 1500);
```

What can we do about it? Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: You can try using **Developer Tools** in your browser, where you go the **Network** tab and see if the MP4's link path is listed there. If yes, then you can open and play the MP4 in a new tab. Try Chrome browser for this. Might be easier to watch the video file itself separately rather than try to modify the source code of the web page to bypass speed control. **PS:** Your plan is not going to work. If you watch at `x2` speed, how will you explain a finish time of `325` mins when the full info/solution is not given until the `650` minute?

Comment: Hello.
Nobody questions whether I watch the videos or not. It is enough if it only shows as watched on the system. That's why I don't want to watch a 650 minute training video. It does not matter. I asked for help to see if there is a short way to get rid of this. Thank you